# Error in stri_length: invalid UTF-8 byte sequence detected; try calling stri_enc_toutf8()

Tags: r, shiny, encoding, export

I have created a R Shiny app that downloads a xlsx.file in the end (usually).
But I came over a case were it does not work and interrupts the process shortly before exporting the exel file (that I create with openxlsx in R Shiny) with following error message:

> Error in stri_length: invalid UTF-8 byte sequence detected; try
> calling stri_enc_toutf8()

And I cannot find the mistake. The weird thing is that I can save that file outside my R Shiny app with the same command. But not inside R Shiny.

How could I figure out which string causes that problem?

I checked the data frame that gets created within R Shiny:

```
dput(apply(df_new_final[, sapply(df_new_final, class) == 'character'],2,function(x) stri_enc_isutf8 (x)))

structure(c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, NA, NA, TRUE, NA, NA, TRUE, NA, NA, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, NA, 
TRUE, TRUE, NA, TRUE, TRUE, NA, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE), dim = 9:10, dimnames = list(NULL, c("Unternehmensname", 
"Art", "alpha_code", "fisch_nr", "fisch_gr", "Auswertungskategorie", 
"Haltung", "Einheit", "rbMeldewege", "Anmerkung")))
```

I checked the file path for potential troublemakers:

```
stri_enc_isutf8(new_doc)
[1] TRUE
```

I don't think that these "NA" values cause the problem, do they? And I checked the length..by using nchar - the longest is 85.

How could I solve that problem?

Comment: Could you include more code? A minimal Shiny app which reproduces the problem would be helpful.

Comment: I needed to to define the file encoding in every importad data file. That was causing the issue

Comment: I would share the data if I could but there are confidential!